# How to calculate s1 and s2 for vector additions

Tags: linear-algebra, plane-geometry

I have attached the question i need help with. I have solved from part a to part c, but dont really understand how to workout part d and part e, can someone please explain what those equations mean and how to go about solving them.[image]

Comment: Can you calculate OA?

Comment: Yes..OA is (1,-2,1)

Comment: OK. Then you can also calculate OB and OC, so what is stopping you from solving $s_1OA+s_2OB=OC$?

Comment: Well, you just have to write out the components of the scaled vectors. For example, $s_1 OA = (s_1, -2 s_1 , s_1)$. Then add the vectors together and you'll get a system of equations.

Comment: I understand s1 and s2 values will be some scalar, but how do I solve for that? Thats where im confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (e) you have to solve:

$s_1(1,-2,1)+s_2(3,1,-2)=(5,1,-2)$.

We get the system

$s_1+3s_2=5$

$-2s_1+s_2=1$

$s_1-2s_2=-2.$

Can you proceed ?